# .NET - high memory usage by clr.dll and native heaps

Tags: .net, memory-leaks, windbg, heap-memory

I have been performing memory leak analysis using DebugDiag for a .NET application which has shown continuous increase in memory.

After several test dumps and then capturing dumps over a day, I see that the module `clr.dll` has 5.08 MB of allocations in first dump, 286.4 MB of allocations in second and 609.56 MB in the third.

Specifically, the rise is in allocations caused by `clr!DoNDirectCall__PatchGetThreadCall+7b` which has 894.33 KB allocation in first, 280.85 MB in second and 601.13 MB in third. Here are some of the call stacks from the third dump -

```
Call stack sample 1

Address   0x00730074`00210048 
Allocation Time   00:09:03 since tracking started 
Allocation Size   34 Bytes 


Function   Source   Destination 
clr!DoNDirectCall__PatchGetThreadCall+7b       
mscorlib_ni+b9597b       
mscorlib_ni+b940ed       
mscorlib_ni+b9513e       
System_Management_ni+dc561       
System_Management_ni+aa364       
System_Management_ni+e4616       

Call stack sample 2

Address   0x00730074`00210048 
Allocation Time   00:05:00 since tracking started 
Allocation Size   34 Bytes 


Function   Source   Destination 
clr!DoNDirectCall__PatchGetThreadCall+7b       
mscorlib_ni+9bb2cc       
mscorlib_ni+b934aa       
System_Management_ni+dc714       
System_Management_ni+acb99       
System_Management_ni+e41a5       


Call stack sample 3

Address   0x00730074`00210048 
Allocation Time   00:05:00 since tracking started 
Allocation Size   34 Bytes 


Function   Source   Destination 
clr!DoNDirectCall__PatchGetThreadCall+7b       
mscorlib_ni+9bb2cc       
mscorlib_ni+b934aa       
System_Management_ni+dc714       
System_Management_ni+acb99       
System_Management_ni+e41a5       
0x6448017AE50
```

What could be causing this and how do I find out more about this ?

***Also, my code uses the avaliable C# methods to run remote WMI queries and retrieve that data.***

In addition, my Native Heaps usage also increases. There are 40 native heaps for my application. The memory usage of the last heap always increases. Its total usage goes from 67.57 MB to 1.59 GB to 3.82 GB. What could be the cause of this, and is this related to `clr`'s usage ?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/paullou/archive/2011/06/28/debugging-managed-code-memory-leak-with-memory-dump-using-windbg.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use

> !dumpheap -stat

at each stage. You may be able to find which type is getting increased drastically at each stage. On those objects use

> !gcroot
>   <"addr">

to find which object is holding it from getting garbage collected.